# How to send a request with TLS 1.2 only with node.js inside a container?

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, https, tls1.2

I'm trying to consume an internal HTTPS service with node inside a container and getting the following error:

```sh
# node src/fetch.js 
Error: write EPROTO 140284687652672:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16) {
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

But if I run the exact same code outside the container (on my machine) it just runs fine.

I'd been googling for a solution but I just keep finding that I'm trying to consume and HTTP service using HTTPS.

Aditionally, this is the result if I run the same URL using cURL inside the container:

```sh
# curl https://my-internal-secure-service.com/apitra/v1/health --verbose
*   Trying 10.56.13.17...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-internal-secure-service.com (10.56.13.17) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Talking with the people who created this service told me that the service is *only* using TLS 1.2 but I have no idea how to specify that kind of parameter with node.

I found the `secureProtocol` (https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) option for TLS and after trying it with the value `TLSv1_2_method` the same thing happened.

Anyone have a clue to what is happening here?

Here are some versions:

- **Docker version:** 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
- **Docker compose:** 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
- **Docker image:** node:12.14.1
- **node version**: 12.14.1.
- **Machine OS:** macOS Catalina 10.15.3

And some results of nmap:

- Inside the container:

```sh
# nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 my-internal-secure-service.com

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-04 14:06 MST
Nmap scan report for my-internal-secure-service.com (10.56.13.17)
Host is up (0.00081s latency).
rDNS record for 10.56.13.17: mockservice.my-company.io
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 88.22 seconds
```

- And in my machine:

```sh
# nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 my-internal-secure-service.com
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-04 14:07 MST
Nmap scan report for my-internal-secure-service.com (10.56.13.17)
Host is up (0.097s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.07 seconds
```

P.S. I don't know if this is important but my machine (MacBook Pro) is connected to a Mac Mini WiFi hotspot, the Mac Mini is connected via ethernet to the corporate network.

Comment: If they use only TLS1.2 then what happens if you do `curl --tlsv1.2 https://my-internal-secure-service.com/apitra/v1/health --verbose`?

Comment: I found something really weird happening, when I switch WiFi networks (first change to a public network and then to the corporate one) and launch an HTTP request using cURL with and without the `--tlsv1.2` the request just works, but after a second a request just fail with the above error, every first request after connecting to the corporate network works as I said, it's a Mac Mini hotspot, weird.

Comment: I tried with a WiFi hotspot but now with a Windows machine and it just works, the problem only happened when using the Mac Mini hotspot, weird.